# SQL injection php fix needed

Tags: php, mysql

Community.
I've read all the posts on SQL injection even the Master one with 4K reputation, still can't grasp the concept . I tried to implement solution yet my application crashes. Please help. Below id my original code and

```
function getStudent($tname,$em)
{// Init values to ""
    $firstname="";
    $lastname="";
    $email="";
    $tychoname="";
    // Connect to the database
    $mysqli = connectdb();
    // Define the Query
    // For Windows MYSQL String is case insensitive
     $Myquery = "SELECT firstName, lastName, eMail, tychoName from Students
     where tychoName='$tname' and eMail='$em'";  
     if ($result = $mysqli->query($Myquery))  {
        /* Fetch the results of the query */         
        while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() )    {
            $firstname=$row["firstName"];       
            $lastname = $row["lastName"];    
            $email=$row["eMail"];       
            $tychoname = $row["tychoName"];                                       
        }    
        $myStudent = new StudentClass($firstname,$lastname,$email,$tychoname);
        /* Destroy the result set and free the memory used for it */
        $result->close();         
    }
    $mysqli->close();
```

And my ugly solution which breaks an application

```
function getStudent($tname,$em) {   

    // Init values to ""
    $firstname="";
    $lastname="";
    $email="";
    $tychoname="";
    // Connect to the database
    $mysqli = connectdb();

    // Define the Query
    $Myquery = "SELECT firstName,lastName,eMail, tychoName 
                from Students
                where tychoName=? and eMail=?";
    if ($result = $mysqli->prepare($Myquery)) {
        $result->bind_param("ss",$tname,$em);
        $result-> execute;
        /* Fetch the results of the query */         
        while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
            $firstname=$row["firstName"];       
            $lastname = $row["lastName"];    
            $email=$row["eMail"];       
            $tychoname = $row["tychoName"];                                       
        } ....
```

Error meassage HTTP 500. SWE id 200. WASC Id 13.Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Breaks" and "crashes" are not actual error messages, nor sufficient observations to fix anything.

Comment: my apologies. Error message HTTP 500

Comment: At least complete the `}` so the code makes some kind of sense.

Answer (score 0):

The `MYSQLI::execute;` is a method and not a property so instead of

```
$result-> execute;
```

code it as

```
$result-> execute();
```

> In future while debugging add

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('log_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

> to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
>   generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

More wrong that I thought

```
function getStudent($tname,$em) {   

    $mysqli = connectdb();

    // Define the Query
    $Myquery = "SELECT firstName,lastName,eMail, tychoName 
                from Students
                where tychoName=? and eMail=?";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($Myquery)

    $stmt->bind_param("ss",$tname,$em);
    $stmt-> execute;
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    /* Fetch the results of the query */         
    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
        $firstname=$row["firstName"];       
        $lastname = $row["lastName"];    
        $email=$row["eMail"];       
        $tychoname = $row["tychoName"];                                       
    } ....
```

Comment: thank you, just changed it, still the same issue. I know I've messed up most likeli with this $Myquery = "SELECT firstName,lastName,eMail, tychoName 
                from Students
                where tychoName=? and eMail=?";

Comment: I implemented    your display message. and it gives me  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_assoc()  that is this line of code :while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() )

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the space between **$result->** AND **execute();**

Or replace

```
$result-> execute();
```

with

```
$result->execute();
```